# No surname in my passport

Tags: visas, passports, paperwork, australia

Surname field is blank in my passport. My full name is in "given name", so will that be a problem while applying for a study visa to Australia?

My actual name:

```
surname: Ganta
given name: Dheeraj
```

In passport:

```
surname:
given name: Ganta Dheeraj
```

Comment: do not post the same question on more stack exchange sites.

Comment: According to your profile your name is `Ganta Dheeraj Kumar`, is this variation listed anywhere (like say, in your birth certificate)?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid My name in birth certificate is only "Ganta Dheeraj". But, surname field is empty in my passport

Comment: As long as what is on your birth certificate matches what is on your passport, you will not face problems.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Will i be able to split my name as Surname: "Ganta" and First name: "Dheeraj" after going to Australia?

Comment: What do you mean by "after going to Australia"?  If you're planning on becoming an Australian or something, yes, you can change your name.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it won't be a problem.  This is a common enough situation that visa processing officers will have seen it before, just enter your names exactly as they're listed in the passport.

See also: [In which countries are the visitor's first name and last name compulsory?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/in-which-countries-are-the-visitors-first-name-and-last-name-compulsory)

Comment: Will i be able to split my name after going to Australia?

Comment: You don't want to do that; your legal name is that which is listed on your government issued id.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Actually "Ganta" is my surname and "Dheeraj" is my first name but there is no surname in passport can i split my name after going to Australia?