# Single name repeated as first name and last name on Schengen visa

Tags: visas, passports

I have only a single name on passport. On visa, my first name is repeated as last name. On visa, it is showing as Karan Karan while on passport it is 'Karan''. Would it pose any problem.

Answer (score 8):

**No problem**.  [Single names are common](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/in-which-countries-are-the-visitors-first-name-and-last-name-compulsory/2), and duplicating them is a common "hack" for entering them on systems that insist on two names.