# What to fill in Schengen Visa Application 'Surname' field, if no Surname on Passport?

Tags: schengen, passports

What should i fill in the `Surname` field while applying for Schengen Visa, if no surname on my passport?

Shall i leave it blank or put my `First Name` in the `Surname` field too?

Comment: The answer is different, depending on whether you have only one name, or you have a first name and surname which were both printed in the First Name field of your passport. Which of these describes you?

Comment: Not sure why this has been marked duplicate. the first one is more around the visa issued with same name repeated but my question is, should i fill first name in the last name field while applying or leave it empty?

Comment: surname on my passport is blank. Given name : "Akki" , Surname : ""

Comment: Then, see [the first linked answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/42600/3221).

Comment: :) apologies but that is post application, mine is pre application. I am going to leave it empty anyways while applying.

Comment: @AkkiA : Did you manage to find solution for this? I have same issue for Schengen visa.

Comment: In case of paper application (Czech Republic) I left it empty and in case of online application (Italy) I entered first name. Both time I was given visa without any issues.