# My name is printed twice in my Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, passports

In the Schengen visa, my name is printed twice. Is this going to be a problem? Can I travel on this visa?

In my passport, I have only my given name. In the visa, it is issued to "Ravi Mehta Ravi Mehta" because, in my passport, surname is blank and my given name shows as "Ravi Mehta."

Surname is mandatory on the visa application form and it appears that they copied given name into the surname field.

Comment: Call the consulate and they will fix it.

Comment: A very, very similar question exists, although arguably Dorothy's answer here is more useful than on the other question: [Single name repeated as first name and last name on Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42600/single-name-repeated-as-first-name-and-last-name-on-schengen-visa)

Comment: This is to update all who have the same issue. I just completed my travel and I didn't face any problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it's a bit confusing, it should not present a problem, as it does coincide with your passport. More importantly, you provided your biometric data as part of the process of obtaining your visa. At the border, that will be checked to confirm your identity, along with your passport, visa, and any other documentation you are carrying.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue for my wife's Schengen visa. I wrote to the consulate; they mentioned it's a regulation, which I feel means if your passport doesn't carry a surname, the consulate is required to repeat your given name twice on the visa. I am hoping it will be OK as we plan to travel soon.

Answer (score 9):

This is a standard process. I don't have surname in my passport but it is a mandatory field on visa, so name is repeated twice at most places. Other countries may put surname as NA or even a + sign.
So in summary you will be fine, i have travelled all my life with name repeated twice or with NA or with + sign...All works