# Passenger Name - Flight Booking Passenger only have First Name in Passport

Tags: air-travel, saudi-airlines

I have bought Delhi-London return flights for 4 on Saudi Airlines.
2 of the passengers only have ‘First name’ in their passports, hence i have used the same in ‘First Name’ and ‘Last Name’ while booking the tickets, as that is generally a common practice suggested by many airlines.

Saudi Airlines do not mention anything about this situation on their website and when i called their UK helpline, they were not very sure

Do you see travelers encountering any problem at airport because of this?

Comment: Related: [In which countries are the visitor's first name and last name compulsory?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/in-which-countries-are-the-visitors-first-name-and-last-name-compulsory)

Answer (score 2):

I called two persons who work for Saudia (ticketing agents), they both said adding the first name in both fields should work, one of them said he would add "MR" as the first name and then add the only name as the last name, either way it should work.

They also mentioned there is no clear policy regarding this and it might be confusing for people, but once the passport is found with one name people usually accept any of the solutions above. So no worries, you will be fine.