# Visa issues, surname of father

Tags: visas

I have a binomial name - Sammy Kumar,
name of my father is monomial - Rajiv (no surname)

Will there be any problem in applying for visa to western countries(EU & USA) ?

Comment: What kind of visa do you want to apply for ? "Western countries" is rather vague, though I suspect this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I can't imagine that a country would reject you for a visa simply because your father has no surname.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20061/in-which-countries-are-the-visitors-first-name-and-last-name-compulsory/

Answer (score 5):

This is such a common occurrence in many countries that there are procedures for it. People with one name can and do get visas.

The instructions for the DS-160 form, for applying for a US visa, state that for people with one name, you [enter the single name in the Surname: field, and enter `FNU` in the Given name: field](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/forms/ds-160--online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/frequently-asked-questions.html).

> **Help: Surnames**
>
> Enter all surnames (or family names) exactly as they are written in your passport. If only one name is written in your passport, enter that as your “Surname.”
>
> **Help: Given Names**
>
> If your passport does not include a first or given name, please enter 'FNU' (meaning “first name unknown”) in the space for “Given Names.”

Comment: Couldn't find something like that regarding Schengen visas

Comment: I can't find anything definitive for any Schengen country from a quick search. I expect that contacting the relevant consulate for instructions is the best thing to do.

Comment: You generally don't need to specify name of your father anywhere in Schengen visa. Even so, I'm sure something like 'n/a' will work.

Answer (score 2):

It says here in the US consulate website: http://chennai.usconsulate.gov/temporary-visitors/faqs.html

> **What if I do not have a first name? What if I do not have a surname?**
>
> If your visa is approved, visas will be printed as your name appears
>   in your passport. If you do not have a first name or surname, your
>   entire name will be printed on the surname field of the visa. Your
>   first name will be printed as "FNU" (first name unknown).
>
> By having "FNU" listed as your given name on your visa, you may have
>   difficulty obtaining a driver’s license and social security card in
>   the United States. If you would like to correct the surname and given
>   name fields on your passport biographic data page, you must have an
>   observation made in your passport by the Indian Passport Authorities.
>   In order for your name to be correctly printed on your visa, you must
>   have this observation made before coming for your interview.